# Remove list items with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list where I want to remove the first list item from when clicked on a button

HTML code

```
<div id="vakjesdiv">
    <ul>
        <li class="verwijder">
            <img class="aanbieding" src="images/jack.png" /><span id="timer"></span>

        </li>
        <li class="verwijder">
            <img class="aanbieding" src="images/kpn.png" /><span id="timer2"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="verwijder">
            <img class="aanbieding" src="images/mac.png" />
        </li>
        <li class="verwijder">
            <img class="aanbieding" src="images/pathe.png" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<button id="testbutton">Button</button>
```

jQuery code

```
//AANBIEDING VERWIJDEREN

$("button").click(function () {
    $(".verwijder").remove();
});
```

I've tried different things but I cant find the problem. Anyone able to help me out? :)

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to remove first `li` item then you can use jquery [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```js
$("button").click(function () {
    $(".verwijder").eq(0).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vakjesdiv">
    <ul>
        <li class="verwijder">
            <img class="aanbieding" src="images/jack.png"><span id="timer"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="verwijder">
            <img class="aanbieding" src="images/kpn.png"> <span id="timer2"></li>
    <li class="verwijder"><img class="aanbieding" src="images/mac.png"></li>
    <li class="verwijder"><img class="aanbieding" src="images/pathe.png"></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <button id="testbutton">Button</button>
```

Comment: Hmm, looking good and test works like I want it to work. But it doesnt do anything in my code... With the code I gave in my example it didnt do anything aswell. Probally something else I messed up!?

Comment: Probably yes. Did you include jquery library? Also there are any errors in console?

Comment: Yea I did include it. I do have a working photoslider and other stuff. There are no errors in the console...

Comment: There are no reason not to work :) Probably is something else. Do you have any live example?

Comment: I do have a live example but the maximum amount of users is already logged in at this moment (it is some crap server from school).

I've tried to enter the code in jsfiddle but I cant get it to work there aswell. strange because its working in the code snippet...

http://jsfiddle.net/36sphwom/

Comment: You didn't include jquery in your example. Here is the correct one  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36sphwom/3). You can add jquery in jsfiddle from the menu in the left.

Comment: I've uploaded it. you can find it here
http://eduweb.hhs.nl/~11028416/html/

It should remove the first image (the one with the timer on it)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("ul .verwijder:first-child").remove();
```

This will remove the first child that meets the select statement.

jQuery `first-child` selector: http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

with `$( ".verwijder" ).remove();` you delete all list items. You want to use `$( ".verwijder:first-child" ).remove();` or `$( ".verwijder" ).first().remove();` to remove the first list item only per click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove first list item:

```
 $( ".verwijder" ).first().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
$("#vakjesdiv .verwijder:first").remove();
```